# Constraint to apply on number of bonds for Portfolio Opimization

Tags: optimization, portfolio

I am exploring to apply Limited no of bonds (out of 1000 or more available bonds) to achieve different strategies? Can you please help me with reference and examples on this if already written?

Eg: Client has given me to invest $100K to invest in 5 different bonds (out of available 1000 bonds) to achieve Maximize yield. How should I apply this limit (no of bonds should be 5) in my Python code?

The way we use to limit the no of weights constraint as weights /= np.sum(weights), so in same way can we use some syntax to limit the number of stocks.

Comment: Maximize yield? That means you just can sort the data and pick the most yielding instruments.

Comment: Correct, I can pick the row with maximum return or Sharpe Ratio. But I want to add the constraint that no of stocks should be limited to 5 (out of given 1000 Bonds). Any suggestion how to apply that in code?

Comment: You can pick the single best one.

Comment: If the individual bonds have a specific amount, you may need to mix and match. I think this is not very difficult to do with a mixed-integer programming model.